# Getting errors "unexpected extra arguments" and "got an unexpected keyword argument" when using click with multiple functions

Tags: python, command-line, command-line-arguments, python-click

I am making a program in which the `click` module is used to parse the command line arguments.

The `-r` and `-t` parameters should be passed to the first function and `-f` and `-l` to the second function.

I gave the following inputs through command line arguments, but it is not accepting inputs for the second function and giving the error like "extra arguments".

How can I use the `click` module with multiple functions?

Input:

```
PS D:\FinIQ\LoadTest> python ram.py -r 80 -t 10 --firstname john --lastname doe
Usage: ram.py [OPTIONS]
Try 'ram.py --help' for help.

Error: Got unexpected extra arguments (john doe)
TypeError: LoadMemory() got an unexpected keyword argument 'firstname'
```

```
import sys, psutil
from multiprocessing import Pool
from multiprocessing import cpu_count
from psutil import virtual_memory
import time
from functools import partial
import click

@click.command()
@click.option("--mempercent", "-r",default=70, prompt="how much ram you want to consume:" ,help="RAM %:")
@click.option("--timesec","-t", prompt="time for which ram to be consumed:",
              help="enter time in seconds")

@click.option("--firstname", "-f" , prompt="enter firstname" ,help="firstname")
@click.option("--lastname", "-l", prompt="enter lastname" ,help="lastname")


def LoadMemory(mempercent, timesec):
    currentMemory = virtual_memory().percent
    print('Current utilized memory = ', currentMemory, "%")

    while mempercent <= currentMemory:
        print('Already utilzed! ')
        print('How much memory to be stressed(%)?')
        mempercent = int(input())
    MemToFillMore = int(mempercent - currentMemory)
    new_list = [0] * 10485760 * MemToFillMore
    print('After loading memory utilized=', virtual_memory().percent, "%")
    timeint = int(timesec)
    time.sleep(timeint)
    new_list.clear()
    print('After clearing memory utilized=', virtual_memory().percent, "%")


def name(firstname, lastname):
    print("full name is:" + firstname + " " +  lastname)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    LoadMemory()
    name()
```

Comment: You would need to create a function that would accept all those arguments, and that function will then invoke the appropriate functions with the appropriate arguments.

Comment: maybe you should use @click with function `myfunction(mempercent, timesec, firstname, lastname):` and it should run `LoadMemory(mempercent, timesec)` and `name(firstname, lastname)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `@click` with function which gets all arguments and later it runs `LoadMemory(mempercent, timesec)` and `name(firstname, lastname)`

```
import sys, psutil
from multiprocessing import Pool
from multiprocessing import cpu_count
from psutil import virtual_memory
import time
from functools import partial
import click

@click.command()
@click.option("--mempercent", "-r", default=70, prompt="how much ram you want to consume:", help="RAM %:")
@click.option("--timesec","-t", prompt="time for which ram to be consumed:", help="enter time in seconds")
@click.option("--firstname", "-f", prompt="enter firstname", help="firstname")
@click.option("--lastname", "-l", prompt="enter lastname", help="lastname")
def myfunction(mempercent, timesec, firstname, lastname):
    LoadMemory(mempercent, timesec)
    name(firstname, lastname)
    
def LoadMemory(mempercent, timesec):
    currentMemory = virtual_memory().percent
    print('Current utilized memory = ', currentMemory, "%")
    while mempercent <= currentMemory:
        print('Already utilzed! ')
        print('How much memory to be stressed(%)?')
        mempercent = int(input())
    MemToFillMore = int(mempercent - currentMemory)
    new_list = [0] * 10485760 * MemToFillMore
    print('After loading memory utilized=', virtual_memory().percent, "%")
    timeint = int(timesec)
    time.sleep(timeint)
    new_list.clear()
    print('After clearing memory utilized=', virtual_memory().percent, "%")

def name(firstname, lastname):
    print("full name is:" + firstname + " " +  lastname)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    myfunction()
```